# Branch.io statistics

Tags: ios, branch.io

I use Branch.io for invite new users to our app from promoters. We generate links with parameter *from_promoter_id*. Every promoter has own link. Users download and install app (iOS and Android). It's work, great! But also we need to track:

1. clicks to link;
2. app installs from link;
3. installed app opens (we do this from app);
4. user registers (we do this from app also);

So, we need collect info like

```
<promoter_id>  <clicks> <app_installs> 
 123              3           2
 111              10          0
                 ...
```

from Branch API.

How can we get this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: there is currently no way to retrieve this data for individual links directly via API calls.

However, you can forward it from Branch into your own system in real time as the events occur. The Branch [webhooks feature](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/webhooks/overview/) is designed to do exactly this!

If you're interested in mass exports of the data, you might also look into the [data export API](https://dev.branch.io/methods-endpoints/data-export-api/guide/)